# How to crop all the values withing a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, substr

Here is an example array. The value formatting is HH:MM:SS

```
$array = ['17:31:05', '17:31:06', '17:31:07' ...etc...];
```

What I need to do is remove the seconds and the colon before from all values within the $array.  My attempt was to do the following, but it did not work.

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $val = substr($val, 0, -3);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your questions example code you modify `$val` and not the `$array`.

Instead modify the `$array`:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $array[$key] = substr($val, 0, -3);
}
```

or

```
foreach($array as &$val){
    $val = substr($val, 0, -3);
}
unset($val); # remove the reference on $val - recommended child protection
```

I recommend the first one since reference variables are somewhat error-prone (harder to understand).

Comment: You should add in your question that the original code doesn't work because the array value is _copied_, not referenced unless specifically told to using an `&`

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not too far off, you just put it in the wrong manner onto the array. Look the following different example:

```
$removeSeconds = function($val) {
    return substr($val, 0, -3);
}

$arrayWithoutSeconds = array_map($removeSeconds, $array);
```

The (anonymous) function contains basically your code and then it uses the `array_map` function to *map* that function on to the array.

If you prefer to use `foreach` this is possible as well, however if you want to write into `$val` in your case, it must be a reference to the value inside the array and this is not always straight forward.

For an array (that is not a reference and not containing any references as "values"), it works as the following:

```
foreach ($array as &$val) {
               ### ^-- iterate over a reference (PHP variable alias)
    $val = substr($val, 0, -3);
}
unset ($val); ### remove the reference (it does not unset the last array element!)
```

Even the `unset` operation after the `foreach` is technically not necessary, it's recommended so that you can not set `$val` later on in your code (and then changing the last value of the array).

This is why it is most often more simple to iterate over keys and values, then writing to the specific element directly:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $array[$key] = substr($val, 0, -3);
}
```

As you can see for all these different cases you could have used the (anonymous) function as on top, therefore using it in the first place would have spared you to change most code. You also have a common mapping situation here, so I think it's most applicable. However this can differ, so keep your mind open and use what you deem fit best in your concrete situation.

Comment: @Willow: http://php.net/foreach has this also. Take a look there as well if you run into problem with `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

You cant use foreach loop for that like this. Use for loop instead

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $array[$i] = substr($array[$i], 0, -3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just to clarify for the future: I cannot use foreach loops for editing the keys or values?

Comment: You can use foreach in this case.

Comment: @Willow: Sure you can. With references, but beware of the side-effects.

Comment: But you never change key with that.

Answer (score 3):

That's because in a foreach the value of the current element is copied over to the `$val` variable.

Set `$array[$key]` with the value you want, and it'll work.

Comment: +1 for an actual explanation as to why the original code doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Simple and short solution:

```
$array = array_map(function($time) {
    return substr($time, 0, -3);
}, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This shoud work fine

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=:\d\d):\d+/', '', $array);
```

or if you need an additional actions inside your loop, do

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $array[$key] = substr($val, 0, -3);
}
```